# cordova invalid image path AppIcon83.5x83.5

Tags: ios, cordova

My cordova version is `7.1.0` and cordova-ios version is `4.5.3`

When I try to upload my app to appstore with ApplicationLoader, it returns

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon83.5.x83.5'"

Here is the icons section for ios in my `config.xml`

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
</platform>
```

I can successfully build and run the app in simulator either via xcode or cordova cli.

I have tried deleting `node_modules`, `platforms`, `plugins` folders and then re-installed and re-added ios platform etc... few times but that didn't help either.

Not sure what's going on. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is your app icon of size 83.5x83.5 , which is missing. its double size icon is present as i can see in your config.xml file. Please also include that icon also.

You can add the app icon manually and edit it in your config.xml file

try to upload your app with this solution.

Comment: Is there a non @2x version of `icon-83.5` ? What will be the actual height and width then? Such an icon is not listed in the docs: cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html  apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: i think their is confusion, please do not combine native development icons with the hybrid development icons. You app is hybrid technology based i guess, so please strict to it. Please check for the icon for @2x is available in your directory or not .    Also the the height and width is same 83.5

Comment: Based on your comments, I've tried adding `<icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5.png" width="167" />` then `<icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5x83.5.png" width="167" />` but none worked. 
Can you explicitly say what you mean and what I should try?